# Recreate handles with jquery rotatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

Hi I am currently using this minified plugin from [godswearhats](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable/master/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js)
To call the plugin

```
$('#em_1').rotatable();
```

Here is my html code

```
<div class="draggable paragraph ui-draggable ui-resizable active resizableborder "id="em_1">
    asdasd123123
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se active-resizable" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n active-resizable" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w active-resizable" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s active-resizable" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e active-resizable" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw active-resizable" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne active-resizable" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw active-resizable" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-rotatable-handle ui-draggable active-rotatable"></div>
</div>
```

Now there is function in my code that removes this part because i need to.

```
 <div class="ui-rotatable-handle ui-draggable active-rotatable"></div>
```

And after that function i need to recreate the rotatable handle. I am able to reappend the handle but when calling `$('#em_1').rotatable();` the events are lost. I think there is a problem with the plugin itself but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the link to the plugin https://raw.githubusercontent.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable/master/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js

Comment: `$('#em_1').rotatable();` and `$('#em_').rotatable();` are different (note the 1).

Comment: Also, you can use http://api.jquery.com/detach/ on the element you want 'removed' and put it back later with the events intact.

Comment: @HamzaKubba oops it was a typo sorry. Edited my question.

Comment: See my note about detach, I believe it solves your problem? You detach that `ui-draggable` `div` and readd it later when you want it.

Comment: Hey that solved my problem thank you! Please post that so I can mark that as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(elem).detach()` (http://api.jquery.com/detach) on the element you want 'removed' and put it back later with the events intact.